# Error: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This question was already asked a few times but, after reviewing all relevant posts, I still cannot find the solution.
I am running a VPS (on Ubuntu 14.04) and have the following Apache directives to block spam bots:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Yandex|GozaikBot|EveryoneSocialBot) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MJ12bot|Ezooms|Ahrefs|AndersPinkBot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

When I emulate HTTP requests with user agent matching any of these bot names, as expected, I see "Forbidden" and "You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server", but I also see "*Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*" and, most importantly, in the error log I see records like this one:
"***...AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.***"

My rewrite rules actually have over 60 blocked bots, I just shortened them here to save space. I get a few thousands hits from these bots daily, so my error log is flooded with these AH00124 errors...

Any thoughts on what's wrong with my rewrite rule? Any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

**UPDATE on 4/27/17:**

Maybe it has something to do with my server configuration? I have Nging running in proxy mode in front of Apache and the directives listed above have been setup as HTTP/HTTPS directives for Apache.

Here is what I see in the log when increase log level to "debug":

```
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.858812 2017] [core:error] [pid 6671] [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861026 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3518): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00121: r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861052 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861061 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861067 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861073 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861079 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861085 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861091 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861155 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861163 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:38.861169 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6671] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53115] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /fees.php
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257662 2017] [core:error] [pid 6669] [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257711 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3518): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00121: r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257718 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257722 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257726 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257730 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257734 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257737 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257741 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257744 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257748 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /error_docs/banned.html
[Thu Apr 27 13:26:39.257751 2017] [core:debug] [pid 6669] core.c(3525): [client 199.99.99.99:53116] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem thanks to an **[article](http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/avoiding_rewritebase_with_mod_rewrite.xhtml)** by Michael Orlitzky, who suggested using *RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f* as an "equivalent" of RewriteBase (the answer/comment by @barbocc got me thinking about RewriteBase). While RewriteBase doesn't work in Apache vhosts settings, the "*RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f*" does. Though, instead of "!-f" I am using "!/error_docs/forbidden.html" as I want to block bot access to everything except this file. Here is the final code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/error_docs/forbidden.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Yandex|GozaikBot|EveryoneSocialBot) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MJ12bot|Ezooms|Ahrefs|AndersPinkBot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the research effort and for the source! Helped me a lot :-) Just replacing the rewritebase line did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Yandex|GozaikBot|EveryoneSocialBot) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MJ12bot|Ezooms|Ahrefs|AndersPinkBot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: Changing the last line to RewriteRule .* - [F,L] makes no difference.

Comment: What about: RewriteBase /

Comment: I am getting a syntax error "RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files" when add RewriteBase /

Comment: What kind of options you get in 2nd line?

Comment: I am not sure about your question... I use RewriteOptions inherit because I want this to be applied to all folders. I assume it's the same behavior with Apache directives as if I were using .htaccess...